# Prove that $\frac{1}{f} \in R(x) \text{ on } [a,b].$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f\in R(x)$ on $[a,b]$ and $\frac{1}{f}$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. Prove that $\frac{1}{f} \in R(x) \text{ on } [a,b].$

Where do I begin on this?

Obviously WTS that $f \in R[a,b] \implies \frac{1}{f} \in R[a,b]$. As $f$ is bounded implies that $|\frac{1}{f}|$ is bounded on [a,b]. I am getting stuck past this....

Comment: What is $f \in R(x)$ on $[a,b]$ mean? Do you mean that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then why is it obvious that $\frac 1f \in R[a,b]$ if it exists?

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable than $\frac{1}{f}$ is also?

Comment: The question is asking us to prove that if $f$ is Riemann integrable, and $\frac 1f$ is bounded, then $\frac 1f$ is Riemann integrable. You are saying that this is obvious, but then my point is, why is it obvious?

Comment: Sorry about that, edit.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry for the earlier comments in that case. Now, what you want to do is start by definition. Take any partition of $[a,b]$, and find the upper and lower Riemann sums for this partition. Can you do that? Post it above when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

**Theorem** (*Lebesgue’s Criterion for integrablility*).
Let $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb R$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $f$ is bounded and the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure $0$.

Clearly, the set of discontinuities of $\frac1{f}$ is the same as for $f$. Since, $f$ is Riemann integrable, this set has measure zero. Lebesgue’s Criterion implies that $\frac1{f}$ is integrable.